# Create a timestamp Column in Spark Dataframe from other column having timestamp value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, unix-timestamp

I have a spark dataframe having a timestamp Column.

I want to get previous day date of the column.Then add time (3,59,59) to the date.

Ex- value in current column(x1) : 2018-07-11 21:40:00
    previous day date : 2018-07-10
    after adding time(3,59,59) to the previous day date ,it should be like :
    2018-07-10 03:59:59 (x2)
I want to add a column in the dataframe with "x2" values corresponding to "x1" values in all records.

I want one more column with values equal to difference of (x1-x2).totalDays in exact double values

Answer (score 1):

Substracting day and adding time and converting to timestamp type

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import *
>>>df.withColumn('x2',concat(date_sub(col("x1"),1),lit(" 03:59:59")).cast("timestamp"))
```

> ***Caluculating Time and Date difference:***

**Date Difference:-**

Using datediff function we can caluculate date difference

`>>>df1.withColumn("x3",datediff(col("x1"),col("x2")))`

**Time Difference**

Calculate time difference for this convert to **unix time** then subtract x2 column from x1

`>>>df1.withColumn("x3",unix_timestamp(col("x1"))-unix_timestamp(col("x2")))`